# Print Dictionary with commas separating values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv  
import output
fill = input("Enter File name:")
f = open(fill)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
m = open('data.csv', "w")
dict_out = {}
for row in csv_f:
 if row[1] in dict_out:
     dict_out[row[1]] += row[3]
 else:
     dict_out[row[1]] = row[3]
for title, value in dict_out.items():
     m.write('{},'.format(title))
     m.write ('{} \n'.format(value))

m.close()
```

Prints my csv as

```
Title,Detail 
Siding, 50 63 22 68 138 47 123 107 107 93 117 
Asphalt, 49 8 72 19 125 95 33 83 123 144 
Rail, 82 98 89 62 58 66 24 77 120 93 
Grinding, 127 47 20 66 29 137 33 145 3 98 
Concrete, 130 75 12 88 22 137 114 88 143 16
```

I would like to put a comma in between the numbers.  I have tried `m.write(',')` after `m.write('{} \n'.format(value))` but it only adds it after the last one. How can i format it so it will output as

```
Title,Detail 
    Siding, 50,63,22,68,138,47,123,107,107,93,117 
    Asphalt, 49,8,72,191,25,95,33,83,123,144 
    Rail, 82,98,89,62,58,66,24,77,120,93 
    Grinding, 127,47,20,66,29,137,33,145,3,98 
    Concrete, 130,75,12,88,22,137,114,88,143,16
```

Comment: Do you mind using `pandas` ?

Comment: You use a csv reader, why not a use also csv writer then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the best way but you can:

```
for title, value in dict_out.items():
    m.write('{},'.format(title))
    m.write ('{} \n'.format(value.replace(' ', ',')))
```

but you should definetly use csv writter,

```
import csv  
import output

fill = input("Enter File name:")
f = open(fill)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
c = open('data.csv', "w")
m = csv.writer(c)
dict_out = {}

for row in csv_f:
 if row[1] in dict_out:
     dict_out[row[1]].append(row[3])
 else:
     dict_out[row[1]] = [row[3]]

for title, value in dict_out.items():
    m.writerow([title] + value)

c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If value is a string then you need to use value.split(). If it is already a list then you don't need to use the split method.

```
with open('data.csv', "w") as m:
    for title, value in dict_out.items():
         m.write(title + "," +  ",".join(value.split()) + "\n")
```